# Python subprocess launch new chrome tab

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a little pythons script that launches all tabs on startup that I need, in the end there should be a new tab page:
[image]

```
import requests
import subprocess
import time

chrome_path = r'C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe'

if is_this:
    subprocess.Popen([chrome_path, 'example.com'])
    time.sleep(5)
    subprocess.Popen([chrome_path, 'https://exmaple.com'])
    time.sleep(0.2)
    subprocess.Popen([chrome_path, 'http://guthib.com'])
    time.sleep(0.2)
    subprocess.Popen([chrome_path, 'chrome://newtab'])
else:
    subprocess.Popen([chrome_path, 'https://github.com'])
    time.sleep(0.2)
    subprocess.Popen([chrome_path, 'http://testurl.com'])
    time.sleep(0.2)
    subprocess.Popen([chrome_path, 'chrome://newtab'])
```

That all works fine, except the chrome://newtab opens a new chrome window instead of a new-tab-page in the same window.

I literally searched all over the web and could not find a solution, except that using selenium with webdriver, however with them I get soo many problems:

It's not launching with my chrome profile
It shouws a banner that this browser is running aautomated
Windows Defender flaggs it.
newtab als does not work there.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you tried "about:blank"?

Comment: @JeffC That gives me a blank page, I want a new tab like in the screenshot above.

Answer (score 0):

Would you consider using the [Browserist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/) extension to Selenium?

In full disclosure, I'm the author of this package. [Browserist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/) is lightweight, less verbose extension of the Selenium web driver that makes browser automation even easier. Simply install the package with `pip install browserist` and you're ready to go.

Maybe something like this could solve your problem?

```py
from browserist import Browser

with Browser() as browser:
    browser.open.url("https://example.com")
    browser.window.open.new_tab("https://google.com", "tab_2")
    browser.window.open.new_tab("https://github.com", "tab_3")
    browser.window.open.new_tab("http://testurl.com", "tab_4")
    browser.window.open.new_tab("chrome://newtab", "tab_5")

    print("About to quit the browser. Press Y to continue.")
    while browser.prompt.proceed_yes_or_no() is False:
        print("About to quit the browser. Press Y to continue.")
        pass
```

How it looks like:

[image]

Notes:

- When running from a terminal, the browser will be kept open for you to interact and check each tab until you quit by pressing `Y`.
- Small detail: It seems like you're running Chrome on a Mac. Chrome is default for [Browserist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/) on macOS. If you run Windows, Edge will be default, and so you may need to adjust the settings a little if Chrome is preferred.

Comment: Huge thanks that seems great, how about opening a new tab page? Does that work flawlessly?

Yes I'm on windows, sorry quickly found that img on the web.

Comment: I’m sure adding a `browser.window.open.new_tab("chrome://newtab")` works as well. Try it.

Comment: Sadly not the tool I search for, can't even open a chrome instance with my profile.

I just need a way to launch those tabs...

Answer (score 0):

How about opening multiple tabs from a folder of links? It's probably easier to maintain than in code while you retain your Chrome profile and options standard options.

After you've created a bookmark folder, right click on the folder and then select “Open all”.

[image: Right click on shortcuts folder in Chrome]

There a guide here: https://medium.com/@partizion/how-to-open-multiple-tabs-in-chrome-eeaca29563d

Comment: That would work, however I do a lot of work before, for example if Streamer live open twitch, otherwise open youtube music, if time = afternoon open this, if time that open that page etc.

So that would not work reliable